# iconv from UTF-16BE to UTF-8 converts to Chinese like characters

Tags: unix, utf-8, utf-16, iconv

I have more than 1000 sql files in Linux server with `UTF-16BE` encoding. The server encoding of the PostgreSQL instance is `UTF-8` which should not be changed. I tried to convert one of the files using the below command and it converted just fine.

```
iconv -f UTF-16BE -t UTF-8  file_0001.sql -o file_0001.sql
```

But when I looped this script to convert all the files in the folder as below, all the scripts got converted into Chinese like language.

```
for file in *; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then 
        iconv -f UTF-16BE -t UTF-8  "$file" -o "$file"
    fi 
done
```

Can someone help how to convert them correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *iconv* can't read from and write to the same file. Are you sure this is the real command you are executing?

Comment: @Codo, yes, this is the command I executed. Thank you, will try to send output to a different file.

Comment: @Codo thanks it worked. Is this the same case for any file type conversions other than encoding?

Comment: Generally speaking, unix commandline tools cannot read and write to the same file. They typically are streaming (reading/processing/writing, while holding little in memory). In order to read and write the same file, the tool would have to load everything into memory, process, and then write. Or it would need to create extra temporary files and rename things at the end. That's not the typical way unix tools are built. The assumption is that the input and output may be pipes to additional processing.